# How to set onError on images in react native inside flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, imagebackground

I have a page where I list people with their info. I have used Flatlist for rendering the n number of data that I am getting and also for pagination.

```
<FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={this.state.records}
    keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.ServiceRequestID)}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View>
    <ImageBackground
    source={{ uri: this.state.baseUserImagePath + item.ImagePath }}
    style={styles.image}
    imageStyle={{ borderRadius: h2p(48) }}
    />
    //other parts
    </View>
    )}
    onEndReached={()=>{//logic}}
    />
```

I wish to load default user image for images that fail to load (deleted in local server in my case). So, I want to add the onError property in the imagebackground. For a single image I can use

`onError={() => {this.setState({ image: require('../../assets/user.png') });}}` and use `source={this.state.image}`

How can I do this for images inside Flatlist to handle my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a separate component and use it in the flatlist renderItem function.

like:

```
const FlatListComponent = props => {

    const [isError, setError] = useState(false)

    return (
        <View>
            <ImageBackground
              source={isError ? require('show-defaultImage') : { uri: props.image }}
              style={styles.image}
              imageStyle={{ borderRadius: h2p(48) }}
              onError{(e) => setError(true)}
             />
            //other parts
        </View>
    )

}
```

FlatList Code

```
<FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={this.state.records}
    keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.ServiceRequestID)}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <FlatListComponent 
             image={this.state.baseUserImagePath + item.ImagePath}
        />
    )}
    onEndReached={()=>{//logic}}
/>
```